# Print out a specific key in a python loop

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, list, loops

I'm trying to print a certain key from a loop and getting some issues. Tried to search other responses but still having issues.

```
import json
from azure.graphrbac import GraphRbacManagementClient
from azure.graphrbac.models import UserCreateParameters, PasswordProfile
from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials

admin_user_name = ''
admin_password = ''
# e.g. yourcompany.onmicrosoft.com
tenant_id = ""

credentials = UserPassCredentials(
            admin_user_name,
            admin_password,
            resource="https://graph.windows.net"
    )

graphrbac_client = GraphRbacManagementClient(
    credentials,
    tenant_id
)

users = graphrbac_client.users.list();
for user in users:
    print [user['mail_nickname']]
```

the key I only want to extract is called `mail_nickname`

I get this error

```
TypeError: 'User' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I only do `print(user)` that works fine but loads data I don't need.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Isn't it just an attribute of `user`, e.g. `user.mail_nickname`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `user.mail_nickname` rather than `user['mail_nickname']`.
The error occurs when a object doesn't support `get` operator using brackets like `user['id']`.

Or try to `print(dir(user))`. It would help you to check attributes you can use.